# Cassandra Deployement Architecture

Tags: architecture, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra. I have the responsibility to design a basic deployment architecture for a use case. I'd like to know if my solution is correct, and get advice and recommendations from you.

Here is the context: We need to create an application that will present some metrics (Scores, Number of visited pages..) to different kind of users (customers,admins..).

Depending on the requests, some metrics may require the latest available data or not.

We are using third party software that stores RAW DATA into MySQL databases.

Here is the solution that I intend to deploy:

[image: diagram]

The "RealTime DataCenter" will be populated using either Cassandra Triggers or Talend jobs.